# File in use error when copying a directory recursively in C#

Tags: c#, directory, copy

I am trying to copy an entire directory including all sub-directories to another folder on the same drive using the below function:

```
    private static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {
        // Check if the target directory exists, if not, create it.
        if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
        }

        // Copy each file into it’s new directory.
        foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Copying {0}\{1}", target.FullName, fi.Name);
            fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
        }

        // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
        foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
        {
            DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir = target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
            CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
        }
    }
```

Called with:

```
    public void copyTemplate(string templatepath, string destpath)
    {
        DirectoryInfo s = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\templates\template1");
        DirectoryInfo t = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\www_temp\gtest");

        CopyAll(s, t);
    }
```

Which produces the error:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\temp\templates\template1\New folder\alf.txt' because it is being used by another process.
```

The file is not in use by me and third-party software tells me no processes are locking the file so I suspect the copy function is tripping itself up somewhere.

Can anyone shed any light on why this might be happening or suggest a function that would better do the job?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the CopyAll() function with the below solved the issue.

```
public static void CopyFolder(string sourceFolder, string destFolder)  
        {  
            if (!Directory.Exists(destFolder))  
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);  
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);  
            foreach (string file in files)  
            {  
                string name = Path.GetFileName(file);  
                string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);  
                File.Copy(file, dest);  
            }  
            string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceFolder);  
            foreach (string folder in folders)  
            {  
                string name = Path.GetFileName(folder);  
                string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);  
                CopyFolder(folder, dest);  
            }  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider locking access to the files, it shouldn't reduce your speed too much and should avoid any attempts to access the file at the same time.

```
private object lockObj = new object();

lock(lockObj)
{
 //Code to access file
}
```

This should solve your issue.